# How to have every 0 1 possible combination in a NXM matrix?

Tags: matlab

AS the title say. For example, imagine M = 2 and N = 2, I would like to have

```
0 0

0 0
```

SPACE

```
0 0

0 1
```

SPACE

```
0 0
1 0
```

SPACE

```
0 0
1 1
```

SPACE

```
0 1
0 0
```

SPACE

```
0 1
0 1
```

SPACE

```
0 1
1 1
```

SPACE

etc...

**Every time I obtain one of the said matrix, I would need to do a check on it.**

Comment: Not following.  You want the count?  It's just $2^{MN}$.  Or are you after something else?

Comment: I need to have all of the matrice enumerated and make a test on each one. Eventually I will have N and M  close to 40

Comment: @Cher Note that $40^2 = 1600$. How big is $2^{1600}$?

Comment: I'm aware it's really big... I have a recursive function lacking memory, so I wondered if there was a better way to do it...

Comment: @Cher Even if you evaluated billions of matrices per second, evaluating them all would still take you zillions of times the age of the Universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As each of the $MN$ entries can be either $0$ or $1$ there are $2^{MN}$ such.

to enumerate them: Write the integers $\{0,\cdots,2^{MN}-1\}$ in base $2$ (adding zeroes to to left as needed to get $MN$ entries). Then for each such, partition them into $N$ groups of $M$  those are your rows (or columns, as the case may be).

For example, consider $5\times 3$ matrices.  We choose $i=167$, just to pick one.  We easily get $167=10100111_2$ which we write as $000\, 000\, 010\,100\,111$.  Then your rows are $\{0,0,0\}, \{0,0,0\},\{0,1,0\},\{1,0,0\},\{1,1,1\}$  so:    $$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: thx for your answer! Could you add the code I will paste? It took me time to do it so I feel like if someone wants it it would be nice to have the code :
max = 20;
padding = numel(num2str(dec2bin(max)));

padding=strcat('%0',num2str(padding),'s');
for a = 0:max
    virginMatrix = zeros(O,P);

    prematrix = num2str(dec2bin(a));
    prematrix = sprintf(padding, prematrix);
  
    loopLimit = O;
    for i = 1:loopLimit
        positionToPick = 1+ (i - 1)*P;
        virginMatrix(i,:) = str2num(strjoin(num2cell(prematrix([positionToPick : (positionToPick + P - 1)]))));
    end
end

Comment: No problem.  You can post a solution to your own problem...I'd include the code there.

Comment: didn't know I could edityour post lol... added it to your answer for more simplicity

Comment: You need the author's permission to edit.  If you don't mind, I'd prefer that you kept your own solution up.  It is your work, after all, not mine.  Also, I didn't try to run your code and wouldn't want to field questions about it from others.  Third reason:  I upvoted your code!  Don't waste those points!

Comment: sure, I undeleted my answr

Answer (score 1):

My code corresponding to accepted answer solution.

```
max = 5;
padding = numel(num2str(dec2bin(max)));

padding=strcat('%0',num2str(padding),'s');

for a = 0:max
    virginMatrix = zeros(O,P);

    prematrix = num2str(dec2bin(a));
    prematrix = sprintf(padding, prematrix);

    loopLimit = O;
    for i = 1:loopLimit
        positionToPick = 1+ (i - 1)*P;
        virginMatrix(i,:) = str2num(strjoin(num2cell(prematrix([positionToPick : (positionToPick + P - 1)]))));
    end
end

end
```

Comment: (+1) for the code.  I notice it didn't cut and paste properly.  (text cuts off on the side).  I can edit it from your earlier comment or perhaps you'd like to do it yourself?